# Is it appropriate to use cubefs for large-scale machine learning model training?

Tags: machine-learning, storage, cloud-native

I need an open-source distributed file storage system to support data storage related to large models, with relatively high performance requirements. I have learned about the [CubeFS](https://github.com/cubefs/cubefs) project under the CNCF Foundation. Does it meet my requirements?

is there any use cases and installation deployment instructions for CubeFS

Answer (score 0):

I think CubefS is a good choice for storing large models.For specific deployment documents, please see:https://cubefs.io/docs/master/deploy/manual-deploy.html

Comment: thank you，i have deployed and run cubefs in the production environment